# count repeated characters using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to count how many times a character comes in text box.. i done with following code, but it only counts a single character. Want to count each character.

```
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sub").click(function(){
      var str = $("#field").val();
      alert(str.split('b').length-1);
      });
      }); 
      </script>

      <textarea id="field"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="GO" />
```

if i type 'balab' in textarea means it will show b-2  a-2  l-1

Comment: put this in fiddle pls

Comment: your program alerts 2 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over all alphabets and get the occurrence of each:

```
var all="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var str = $("#field").val();
for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++)
{
 var char = all.charAt(i);
 if(str.split(char).length>1)
 console.log(char +"-"+ (str.split(char).length-1));
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dsx2t/)**

Comment: thanks ya,more or less come. But after getting output it gives more alert result.. i.e., if i type 'abba' means output is '22221444444444444444444444' first 2 letters are correct. Help me

Comment: if i change all.length to 'str.length' means output comes. but still one more problem.. input 'aab' means output should be '2  1'.. but i get output like this '2 2 1'

Comment: @ Milind Anantwar, it comes by alphabet order.. i want it in input order

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var yourString = "balab";

var count = yourString.match(/b/g);  
            //b is your char, g is for searching all occurrences in the string
alert(count.length);
```

**UPDATE**

```
function printOccurence(string){
    var unique='';   //unique chars
    for(var i=0; i<string.length; i++){
        if(string.lastIndexOf(string[i]) == string.indexOf(string[i])){
            unique += string[i];
        }
    }
    var occs='';  //result ex. 221
    for(var i=0; i<unique.length; i++){ 
        var re = new RegExp(unique[i], 'g');
        var count = string.match(re);
        occs = occs + count;
    }
    return occs;
}
```

Comment: write me the output that it gives please

Comment: works, but only counts how many 'b'. My task is to check how many times occuring each character. 'balab' means output '221'

Comment: actually where should i place printOccurence(string)? what is string? is it textbox value?

Comment: yes it's textbox value. Copy the function in your .js file

Answer (score 0):

By following code it works

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src='add jquery.js'></script>
    <script>
    var uniqueOccurence = "";
    var str = $("#field").val();
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if(uniqueOccurence.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) < 0)
        uniqueOccurence += str.charAt(i);
    }

    var text = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < uniqueOccurence .length; i++) {
        var char = uniqueOccurence .charAt(i);
        if (str.split(char).length > 1) text +=+ char + str.split(char).length-1       
    }
    $("#charNum").html(text);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <textarea id="field"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="GO" />
  <div id="charNum"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```